# Create map between api and record value

Tags: apex

I need to get a map of API name and record value Map

```
ServiceContract objServiceContract = [SELECT Id, PriceBook2Id,Name From ServiceContract  LIMIT 1];

List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldList=SObjectType.ServiceContract.FieldSets.fieldsetName.getFields();
            for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldList) {
                valuemap.put(f.getFieldPath() , f.Label);
            }
```

I am getting map of field label and api name from field set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple using [getPopulatedSobjectField()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap) method from Sobject.

```
ServiceContract objServiceContract = [SELECT Id, PriceBook2Id,Name From ServiceContract  LIMIT 1];


Map<String, Object> fieldsAPINameToValue = objServiceContract .getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
```

Comment: getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() only return fields with value , if field value is blank it will return nothing.